# Using selenium in a function leads to TypeError

Tags: python, function, selenium

I want to login to multiple websites, so I try to implement a function code. The procedual code below works.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time


options = Options()
chrome_path = "T:/User/WebScrapingExample/Chromedriver/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path,chrome_options=options)
driver.set_window_size(1280, 720) 
driver.get("https://testwebsite/#/")
time.sleep(5)
user = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type=text]")
password = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type=password]")
user.send_keys("xxx")
password.send_keys("xxx")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type=submit]").click()
```

This code below does not work and returns me the following error:

> File
>   "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda4\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
>   line 478, in send_keys
>       {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\langma\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda4\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\utils.py",
>   line 150, in keys_to_typing
>       for i in range(len(val)):
>
> TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()

```
def login(link, username, password, userinput, passwordinput, submitbtn):

        from selenium import webdriver
        from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

        options = Options()
        chrome_path = "T:/user/WebScrapingExample/Chromedriver/chromedriver.exe"
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path,chrome_options=options)
        driver.set_window_size(1280, 720) 
        driver.get(link)
        time.sleep(5)
        user = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(userinput)
        password = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type=password]")
        user.send_keys(username)
        password.send_keys(password)
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(submitbtn).click()

login(link = "https://testwebsite.com/#/", username = "xxx", password = "xxx", userinput = "input[type=text]", passwordinput = "input[type=password]", submitbtn = "button[type=submit]")
```

I guess importing inside a function is also bad practice right? Can somebody help me to get this running?

Comment: Why did you import Options? I can't find any settings of options in your code. Maybe it's unnecessary. I also can't find where you call len(). Can you paste entire error message?

Comment: yes, maybe I don´t to call Options, but it should not matter. Updated the post :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your CSS selector for elements are wrong.

```
userinput = "input[type='text']", passwordinput = "input[type='password']", submitbtn = "button[type='submit']"
```

And you sendkeys password(element) to password(element).

```
password = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type=password]")
user.send_keys(username)
password.send_keys(password)
```

Try to modify as below.

```
password_ele = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(passwordinput)
user.send_keys(username)
password_ele.send_keys(password)  # this password is string from argument
```